# Finding "missing" rows

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

I have an exam database, with 4 tables: users, answers, questions and subjects.

```
user table
U_id | name

subjects table
S_id | Subject

questions table
Q_id | S_id | question | Correct 

answers table
U_id | Q_id  | answers
```

I need to find the number of correct answer per subject, per user.

My query

```
select  U_id,questions.S_id ,count(Q_id) 
from answers inner join questions  on  questions.q_id = answers.q_id
where questions.Correct  = answers.answer
group by answers.U_id,questions.S_id

result:
1 | s1 | 2
1 | s2 | 3
1 | s3 | 1
2 | s1 | 1
2 | s2 | 1
```

That gives me the number of correct answer per subject, but if the user doesn't have a correct answer the S_id is not display, i need to display those with 0.

The result I need is

```
result:
1 | s1 | 2
1 | s2 | 3
1 | s3 | 1
2 | s1 | 1
2 | s2 | 1
2 | s3 | 0
```

Note:  I´m using MySQL, but a MS SQL server answer is also fine.

Comment: something about the inner join... outer join, cross join... too long ago... Try it.

Comment: the given table structure doesn't map to your query

Comment: I added S_id to the questions table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select u.U_id, q.S_id, count(a.q_id) 
from users u
cross join questions q
left join answers a on q.q_id = a.q_id and u.u_id = a.u_id and q.Correct = a.answer
group by u.U_id, q.S_id
```